# php String from user input and from database

Tags: php

I have a problem about this strings

currently i save some strings into the database with simple insert query and cleaning the data by this code

```
mysql_real_escape_string($data)
```

i get the data from the database using a simple query

sample input

```
$saveString = "You're great";
```

saving...

```
Insert into . . . values (mysql_real_escape_string($saveString))
```

now when i get the string i get the `You're great` string

When i use this code

```
$str = str_word_count(strtolower($fromDbString), 1);

print_r($str);
```

It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => You're
    [1] => great 
)
```

But if the string came from the users input in textbox and i use this code.

```
   $str = str_word_count(strtolower($fromUserInput), 1);

    print_r($str);
```

I get something like this:

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => You
        [1] => re
        [2] => great 
    )
```

How do i fix the string from the database to be process like the one from the users input?

I tried `htmlentities()` to check the values and the output was

from db `You're great`
from input `You&#039;re great`

i tried to html decode the string from db but it still outputs `You're great`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return an array that contains all the string words you could try this instead str_word_count

```
$str = preg_split("/[' ]/", strtolower($fromUserInput));
//$str = preg_split("/[' ]/", strtolower($fromDbString));
print_r($str);
```

Comment: Yes, in this part [' ] you add the delimiters for the words found in the String. And this returns an array with every word like your code str_word_count(strtolower($fromUserInput), 1);

Answer (score 2):

You could try to add addslashes():

```php
$str = str_word_count(addslashes(strtolower($fromUserInput)), 1);

print_r($str);
```

Comment: To the user input. I think the database input is already escaped.

Comment: yes it was escaped but i need an output from db to look like in user input

Comment: You can use `stripslashes()` to remove the slashes from the database data.